# Mongo Java Array

Tags: java, mongodb

Quick and hopefully easy question.

```
DBObject res = collection.findOne(new BasicDBObject("_id",id));
// some_array is just an array of strings
Arr = res.get("some_array");
```

What type does Arr need to be? `String[]`? `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java driver will return arrays within the document as a `List` - for your example, you would want Arr to be a `List<String>`.

Comment: No at all.
The Java driver returns Objects, not Arrays/Lists.
Furthermore, by casting some_array to List<String> could trigger a ClassCastException if types mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

res.get() returns an Object, so that you need to do an explicit casting (you need to know the type of *some_array* field.

i.e:

```
List<Integer> values = (List<Integer>)res.get("some_array");
```

This is one of the reasons because I'm not supporter of bringing Java & MongoDB together.